# Node JS how to determine if the sidekiq job is finished

Tags: node.js, promise, sidekiq

In the ruby implementation there are some project implementations which show the statuses of the jobs like [Sidekiq Status](https://github.com/cryo28/sidekiq_status). I wonder whether there is any way to find out if the job have been finished in the Node JS?